# Carbon Emacs does not paste Microsoft Word's copied contents

Tags: text, emacs, ms-word, copy, paste

Not Sure if Stackoverflow is right site.

I'm using carbon emacs 22.0.971 on mac ox 10.6.7. And MS word 12.2.8. I have some text in MS word which i want to copy and paste into emacs. I do the normal procedure cmd C in word, C-y in emacs, but the text does not get copied in emacs, instead it looks a bitmap of the copied text is passed. One big image which can be deleted with one C-d. I can get around it: paste the text in mac ox' text editor. But for me it is new emacs behavior. Is there a way to force emacs to paste the clipboard as plain text?

regards,
Jeroen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `yank` does not not paste from the clipboard, but from the [kill ring](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Kill-Ring.html). Try <kbd>M-x clipboard-yank</kbd> instead.

If you do not want to type that command every time, bind it to some keyboard shortcut, e.g. <kbd>C-x y</kbd>, by putting the following line into your .emacs file:

```
(global-set-key [(control x) (y)] 'clipboard-yank)
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and the above answer did not help.  After looking at the 'yank' helptext, I added this to my .emacs, which seems to work:

```lisp
;; clipboard yank is pasting graphics from MS instead of text.  
;; Strip all properties
(setq-default yank-excluded-properties 't)
```

Comment: This worked for me as well, on Mac OS X 10.6 with Carbon Emacs. When pasting from Numbers and other Mac apps, I was getting images instead of text. Thanks Jonathan.