# Emacs on Mac: copy text from Word 2008 to Emacs

Tags: emacs

When I copy a formatted text from Word 2008 into Emacs, it pastes as an image. I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211915/carbon-emacs-does-not-paste-microsoft-words-copied-contents). But I'm unable to post a comment to that question. I tried clipboard-yank and that doesn't work.

Using: Mac: 10.6.7; Emacs: GNU Emacs 22.3.1 (i386-apple-darwin9.8.0, Carbon Version 1.6.0)

Comment: possible duplicate of [carbon emacs does not paste microsoft word's copied contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211915/carbon-emacs-does-not-paste-microsoft-words-copied-contents)

Answer (score 1):

You could save the text from word as a plaintext document, open it from emacs, and then use emacs' kill-and-yank tools.